# How to properly change the videolist in the Youtube API?

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I am a beginner of android `Youtube API`. I hope I can click on different items to make the player load different videolist.

But every time I click on a different item, I always only keep the first videolist and can't change it correctly to the second videolist.
I don't know how to make the right changes.

```
// click item 3

if (id == 3) {

    curBrowserlist = db.rawQuery("Select  *  from MusicMaster where status = 'A'and genre_id = 'man0003'", null);

     ArrayList < String > mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    curBrowserlist.moveToFirst();

    while (!curBrowserlist.isAfterLast()) {

        mArrayList.add(curBrowserlist.getString(curBrowserlist.getColumnIndex("source_id")));

        curBrowserlist.moveToNext();
    }

    player.loadVideos(mArrayList);
}

//click item 4

if (id == 4) {

    curBrowserlist = db.rawQuery("Select  *  from MusicMaster where status = 'A'and genre_id = 'man0004'", null);

    ArrayList < String > mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    curBrowserlist.moveToFirst();

    while (!curBrowserlist.isAfterLast()) {

        mArrayList.add(curBrowserlist.getString(curBrowserlist.getColumnIndex("source_id")));

        curBrowserlist.moveToNext();
    }

    player.loadVideos(mArrayList);
}
```